# JavaScript simple BitConverter

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitconverter

I need to make simple C# BitConverter for JavaScript. I made simple BitConverter

```
class BitConverter{
constructor(){}
GetBytes(int){
    var b = new Buffer(8)
    b[0] = int;
    b[1] = int >> 8
    b[2] = int >> 16
    b[3] = int >> 24
    return b
}
ToInt(buffer){
    return buffer[0] | buffer[1]<<8 | buffer[2] << 16 | buffer[3] << 24 
}
}
```

GetBytes is giving me same output as c# but toInt not so ... 
toInt don't give me back what I've put into GetBytes (bigger numbers)
example :

```
var a = new BitConverter()
var e = 285128170;
var c =a.GetBytes(e);
var v = a.ToInt(c);
console.log(e) // 2851281703
console.log(c) // <Buffer 27 1b f3 a9 00 00 00 00>
console.log(v) //-1443685593
```

Comment: Hmm. Tried this in node and it seemed to work fine for me. Can you give some examples of what number you put in vs what you get back?

Comment: data :
GetBytes(2851281703) //<Buffer 27 1b f3 a9 00 00 00 00>
ToInt(a) // -1443685593

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is treating your final result as a signed number. You can fix this by ending your bitwise operation with a `>>> 0`, which will force the sign bit to be 0. So for your example:

```
class BitConverter{
    GetBytes(int) {
        var b = new Buffer(8)
        b[0] = int;
        b[1] = int >> 8
        b[2] = int >> 16
        b[3] = int >> 24
        return b
    }
    ToInt(buffer) {
        return (buffer[0] | buffer[1]<<8 | buffer[2] << 16 | buffer[3] << 24) >>> 0;
    }
}

var converter = new BitConverter();
converter.ToInt(converter.GetBytes(2851281703)) // Returns 2851281703
```

From the [documentation of zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift):

> This operator shifts the first operand the specified number of bits to
>   the right. Excess bits shifted off to the right are discarded. Zero
>   bits are shifted in from the left. **The sign bit becomes 0, so the
>   result is always non-negative.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: you made my day!  how can I write GetBytes better? and do I have to?